What is the maximum subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ that only contains $0$ and elements of weight larger than $w$?
For element $x$ in binary linear space $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, $\mathrm{wt}(x)$ is the weight function. Define the set
$$A := \{x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n \mid \mathrm{wt}(x) \ge w\}. $$
What is the largest subspace $V$ such that $V \subseteq A \cup \{0\}$?
Update：
I just realized that this problem is equivalent to finding the maximal size of linear error correcting code with length $n$ and distance $w$, which is still an open problem.

Yes. This is a big open question in coding theory. Books and research articles with thousands of pages have been written to describe partial answers and/or special cases. Particularly for small values of $n$ and $w$. I would thus say that the question is too broad to be answered here (and know general answer is known).

I voted to close this is Needs more focus. The description of that close reason may be a bit misleading, so I want to clarify that the problem (in my opinion) is basically "answering this question well amounts to writing a book".
